# Using std::atomic_flag to handle SIGINT / ctrl-c

Tags: c++, c++17

Using C++ 17 (and not C++ 20), am I using `std::atomic_flag` correctly to handle SIGIN / ctrl-c to shutdown my program?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <csignal>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

std::atomic_flag gShutdownFlag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
static void sigint(int /*sig*/) {
  std::cout << "Received Ctrl-C, initiating shutdown...\n" << std::endl;
  gShutdownFlag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
}

int main() {
  signal(SIGINT, sigint);
  gShutdownFlag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire);

  while (gShutdownFlag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
  }
  std::cout << "Shutting down...\n" << std::endl;
}
```

Calling `test_and_set` before the while-loop makes sense, as it would set the flag to `true`. It feels as if I'm using the wrong thing to do the job however.

I could use std::atomic_flag::test() [1], but it's only available in C++ 20.

[1] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test

Comment: Use `sig_atomic_t` type (which is simple `int` on x86_64). Don't use `signal()` to setup handler, use `sigaction()`. Don't call any functions in signal handler except signal-safe listed in manual.